# Помогите сократить код

Tags: php

Доброе время суток. Помогите в правильном написание следующего кода, возможно ли как то его сократить и оптимизировать?

```
if($myrow['cat'] == 1){ $id = 1;}
if($myrow['cat'] == 2){ $id = 2;}
if($myrow['cat'] == 3){ $id = 3;}
if($myrow['cat'] == 4){ $id = 4;}
if($myrow['cat'] == 5){ $id = 5;}
```

Comment: `$id = $myrow['cat'];`?

Comment: Я даже плюс поставлю хороший вопрос

Comment: http://www.anekdot.ru/id/-9934695/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот ответ

```
$id = $myrow['cat'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Может быть вам нужно, чтобы для $id значения передавались из $myrow['cat'] только в случае, если $myrow['cat'] от 1 до 5, в остальных случаях 0 по умолчанию?

```
$id = ($myrow['cat']>0 && $myrow['cat']<6)?$myrow['cat']:0;
```